# ProtectSection with RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider where does the Key go?

Tags: c#, configuration, encryption, rsa

I am using System.Configuration to encrypt and protect some passwords in a custom  configuration section vis:-.

```
static public void SetPassAndProtectSection(string newPassword)
{

    // Get the current configuration file.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
        ConfigurationUserLevel.None);


    // Get the section.
    MyAppProtectedSection section = 
        (MyAppProtectedSection)config.GetSection(DEFAULT_SECTION_NAME);

    section.DBPassword = newPassword;

    // Protect (encrypt)the section.
    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");

    // Save the encrypted section.
    section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
}
```

This appears to work fine but I need some extra information for my documentation.

Where is the Key stored?

How long is the Key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

User level keys are stored at

> \Documents and
>   Settings{UserName}\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA

Machine-level keys at

> \Documents and Settings\All
>   Users\Application
>   Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

Yours is a user-level key.

Comment: Thanks h0b0  I checked it out and that is correct.  I was a little shocked to discover that the machine level keys location has a default access of 'everyone..read'.  I'm thinking that I will need to use the user level keys because in my case the user of the key is a windows service that runs as a specific account.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Note: location may have changed on later version of windows. The one on my answer was different.

Answer (score 1):

I had a scenario where I needed to grant a local service account access to the RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider key on a Windows 2012 server.

In the end, granting access on C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys did the trick.